# Backup SD ext2 partition

Tags: arch-linux, ext2, sd-card

I have a [Sheeva plug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SheevaPlug) running [ArchLinuxArm](http://archlinuxarm.org/platforms/armv5/sheevaplug) from SD card and I'd like to backup the SD card so I can restore everything in case something goes wrong.

I'd prefer to create an archive file (rootfs.tar.gz) or image file. I found [some instructions](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=35087) but they seem specific to ubuntu. I need something that applies to this specific distro and device for easy restoration.

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd just use `dd`:

```
$ dd if=/path/to/sdcard/device of=sdcard.img
$ gzip sdcard.img
```

Then to restore, do the opposite:

```
$ gunzip sdcard.img.gz
$ dd if=sdcard.img of=/path/to/sdcard/device
```

Comment: can I use `dd` if the system is currently running? - as in backup a live system?

Comment: You *can* but it wouldn't be advised.